# listen for shift keypress within .on() then perform a function with element that attached the listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have a function that listens for a shift key press

```
$("fieldset").on("change", "input[type='checkbox'].shift_selectable_box", function () {
    $(document).on("keydown keyup", listening_for_shift);

         var boxes = $(this).closest("fieldset").find("input[type='checkbox']"),
             any_selected = boxes.filter(":checked").size() > 0;

         if (any_selected) {
             $(document).on("keydown keyup", listening_for_shift);

         } else {
              $(document).off("keydown keyup", listening_for_shift);
         }

     });
});

function listening_for_shift(e) {

   if (e.keyCode == 16) {
       if (e.type === "keydown") {
           console.log(e);
        }

        if (e.type === "keyup") {
           console.log(e)
        }

     }
```

It there a way that I can, when the shift key is down, execute something on the element that called the `listening_for_shift` function: the `input[type=checkbox]` element that was changed?

## **Edit:**

Apparently, I can do something like this:

```
    if (any_selected) {
        $(document).on("keydown keyup", function listening_for_shift(e) {

            if (e.keyCode == 16) {
                if (e.type === "keydown") {
                    console.log(self);

                }
                if (e.type === "keyup") {
                    console.log("no shift")
                }
            }

        });

    } else {
        $(document).off("keydown keyup", listening_for_shift);
    }
```

and the listener will be added. But my `.off()` fails to function.

Comment: Do what exactly when the shift key is down? Also, `e.shiftKey` does seem a lot easier !

Comment: @adeneo find out if another box is ticked, then tick the boxes in between the two

Comment: @adeneo How does `e.shiftKey` make it so much easier. Doesn't that just replace `if (e.keyCode == 16) {` ?

Comment: Something like this then -> http://jsfiddle.net/hwjME/

Comment: I'm not really sure I get this, but you are aware that inside the handler for the change event, the change has already happened, and it's a bit late to start listening for keys, unless you're supposed to first check the box, then hit shift or something like that ?

Comment: @adeneo I find that quite a bit harder to read, but it does work +1

Comment: @adeneo  yeah, you check the box, then listen for `shift`

Comment: But aren't you supposed to hold down shift when checking the box, it's a bit late to listen for keys after the box has changed ?

Comment: @adeneo You check a box, then hit shift, then check another box while shift is down. Then the in between boxes get checked

Comment: Okay, posted an answer that does that !

Answer (score 1):

In your `.off()` call, the 2nd argument is a literal that doesn't exist in the context, as the handler function is declared in the `if` block. Change your code to:

```
function listening_for_shift(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 16) {
        if (e.type === "keydown") {
            console.log(self);
        }
        if (e.type === "keyup") {
            console.log("no shift")
        }
    }
}

if (any_selected) {
    $(document).on("keydown keyup", listening_for_shift);
} else {
    $(document).off("keydown keyup", listening_for_shift);
}
```

Comment: This isn't working for me, can you please make a fiddle? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to listen for key events **before** the change event, inside the event handler the change has already happened, and it's too late to start checking if a key was pressed, and the change event on a checkbox has no concept of keys anyway, as it doesn't listen for key events :

```
$(document).on('keyup keydown', function(e) {
    $(this).data('shift', e.type==='keydown' && e.shiftKey);
});

$(".test").on("change", function (e) {
    if ( $(document).data('shift') ) {
        $(this).prevUntil('[type="checkbox"]:checked')
               .filter('[type="checkbox"]')
               .prop('checked', this.checked);
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hwjME/1/)

Comment: That sort of works....  not when you click a lower box then a higher one. But thanks! What does the `filter` do? This is really nice...

Comment: The filter just filters out the `<br>`'s and any other elements that are also siblings of the checkboxes. 
To go the other way (from a lower to a higher box) you have to use `nextUntil` instead, to do both you'd use both in a slightly different way etc.